# Reflection Cast Each Property to List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to use Reflection to loop through an objects properties and cast each property to a `List<T>`.

```
class MyObj
{
    public List<A> As { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public List<C> Cs { get; set; }
    public List<D> Ds { get; set; }
    public List<E> Es { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that takes an object and I am trying to cast the value of each property to a `List<T>` but it is not working.

```
void ProcessObject(object o)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        Type propertyListType;

        if (TryListOfWhat(propertyType, out propertyListType))
        {
            var propertyValue = (List<propertyListType>)propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
        }
    }
}

public static bool TryListOfWhat(Type type, out Type innerType)
{
    Contract.Requires(type != null);

    var interfaceTest = new Func<Type, Type>(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>) ? i.GetGenericArguments().Single() : null);

    innerType = interfaceTest(type);
    if (innerType != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        innerType = interfaceTest(i);
        if (innerType != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now that I know the property is a `List<T>` and I have the type of `T`, how do I cast the property object value to `List<T>`?

I created another question to explain what I am actually trying to accomplish here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975430/serialize-deserialize-inmemorydatabase

Comment: You can't cast an object to a type not known at compile time. You should post what you're trying to do so we can understand.

Comment: as far as I know, this is not possible.just you can cast them to `IList` but not `List<T>`

Comment: If you're using reflection and you don't know that actual types involved, you have only 2 friends: object and dynamic. At most you can use dynamic but that's it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "dynamic" instead of "var" and keep the property as an object, then it should be the same as calling the List members as always without compile time checking.